# Why an NSDictionary instance can not be passed via delegate between MapView controller and UIImageView controller?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiimage, mkmapview

I'm a beginner of iOS development, my app currently have two separate controller - mapViewController(Left side) and photoViewController(right side), show below:

[Image Link](http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/a74ecc4cjw1dzrwd4waf5j.jpg)

I add some annotation on the map, each annotation contains a photo (shown small size on right accessory in callout).

My idea is if user tap the left accessory which is a blue detail button, the full size photo should appear on right side.

I try to implement it with delegate:

In mapViewController:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    KCFlickPhotoAnnotation *fpa = (KCFlickPhotoAnnotation *) aView.annotation;
    self.photoDictionary = fpa.photo;
    [self photoDictionaryDelegate];
}

-(void)photoDictionaryDelegate
{
    NSDictionary *photoDictionary = self.photoDictionary;
    [spDelegate setPhotoDictionary:photoDictionary in:self];
    //NSLog(@"button pressed");
}
```

In photoViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    mapVC.spDelegate = self;
    [mapVC photoDictionaryDelegate];
}

-(void)setPhotoDictionary:(NSDictionary *)photoDictionary 
                       in:(KCMapViewController *)mapViewController
{
    self.photo = photoDictionary;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.photo); // LINE A
}
```

In photoViewController.h:

```
@interface KCPhotoViewController : UIViewController <setPhotoDelegation>
{
    KCMapViewController *mapVC;
}
```

The LINE A can't work, it seems that the photoDictionary can not reach the photoViewController, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `mvc` and how is it set?  `photoDictionaryDelegate` calls `setPhotoDictionary` which then calls `photoDictionaryDelegate` which then...isn't that an endless loop?

Comment: Anna is right, there is an infinite loop in your code.

Comment: sorry , my mistake. I have already edited the question. mvc is an instance of mapViewController. it is set in 'photoViewController.h',and I add them into the question.